# Gradle: Using 'maven-publish' plugin in custom standalone plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, maven-publish

Almost feeling like spamming after my third question, cause my questions seem so trivial. But I just don't find any help in Gradle Docs for my cases and also other asked questions on stackoverflow weren't helping.

This time: I can't use the `maven-publish` plugin in my own standalone custom plugin. The code of my plugin so far:

```
package com.sample.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;

public class SampleGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {

        project.apply plugin: 'application'
        project.apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        project.apply plugin: 'maven'

        project.publishing.publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.group
                artifactId project.name
                version=project.version
                from components.java
            }
        }

        project.uploadArchives {
            repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                    repository(url: project.Repo_Upload_Internal){
                        authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
                    }        
                    snapshotRepository(url: project.Repo_Upload_Snapshot){
                        authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //this try/catch is not important for my question
        try{
            project.repositories {
                maven {
                    url project.Repo_Gp_Internal
                    credentials {
                        username project.Repo_Gp_User;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(MissingPropertyException e){
            println "Info: '"+e.getProperty()+"' not declared in \\"+project.name+"\\gradle.properties"
        }
    }
}
```

The `publishing` closure is the important part that brings me this error, when I use my plugin in one of my projects:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\quastc\Desktop\Gradle_Projects\Application_RootProject\buil
d.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Application_RootProject'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'sample.sample-groovy-plugin']
   > Cannot create a Publication named 'MavenPublication' because this container
 does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype
of Publication to create. Known subtypes are: MavenPublication
```

Where's my mistake? What did I forget?

If somebody answers, PLEASE let me know HOW you got your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me right now. I don't use the `maven-publish` plugin anymore. Just the `maven` plugin. Then I put this code at the end of my own plugin:

```
    project.configurations {
        deployerJars 
    }
    project.dependencies {
        deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
    }   
    project.uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: project.Repo_Upload_Internal){
                    authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
                }        
                snapshotRepository(url: project.Repo_Upload_Snapshot){
                    authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Further:

I haven't found a way to suppress the uploading of a zip and a tar file. I still need some copy&paste code in the several `build.gradle` files to do this job. It's this code:

```
configurations.archives.with {
    artifacts.remove artifacts.find { it.archiveTask.is distZip }
    artifacts.remove artifacts.find { it.archiveTask.is distTar }
}
```

I'm not able to change that code to work in my custom plugin yet.

Comment: FYI, the code you have to prevent uploading zip and tar files breaks with Gradle 4.x and higher.  I have found a similar workaround that works on 3.x and 4.x Gradle, that appears to do the same thing, which was found on
 https://github.com/georocket/georocket/blob/master/georocket-server/build.gradle
`// do not upload ZIP and TAR distributions to Maven repo
  configurations.archives.with {
      artifacts.removeAll { it.file =~ 'tar' }
      artifacts.removeAll { it.file =~ 'zip' }
  }`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I fixed that error message adding this:

```
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication
```

But then faced other issues and finally ended up using the [nebula-publishing-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin), solving it all

Comment: Building using Groovy might not throw a compile error if MavenPublication is not imported.  The 'does not support creating elements by name alone' error is thrown in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, with gradle 4.10 and maven-publish.

In my custom plugin .groovy:

```
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication

...

project.extensions.configure PublishingExtension, new ClosureBackedAction( {
                publications{
                    mycustompub(MavenPublication) {
                        groupId = project.group
                        artifactId = <artifact name>
                        artifact source: <path to artifact>, extension: 'zip'
                    }
            }})
```

Answer (score 0):

The closure you pass to project.publishing.publications does not have `project` in its context when it executes. This means `MavenPublication` is not in the context of the closure, even though you apply `maven-plugin` to `project`.

If you write the plugin in your build script, it will have `project` as context by default, but the context is different when writing it as a standalone plugin.

You can `setDelegate(project)` on a closure to set the context, then pass it:

```
def publicationsClosure =  {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId project.group
        artifactId project.name
        version=project.version
        from components.java
    }
}
publicationsClosure.setDelegate(project)
project.publishing.publications(publicationsClosure)
```

I had the same error in a plugin and eventually realized what went on when I read this article: http://trickyandroid.com/gradle-tip-2-understanding-syntax/