# sourcesJar task in gradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have inherited a codebase which I suspect was originally built with Gradle 4 (but I don't know for sure). I am using Gradle 5.5.1 and when I run `gradle` I get errors to do with publication to a Maven repo:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'common'.
> Could not find method sourcesJar() for arguments [build_d1u03z05r8d12r3e8b5qq1fxm$_run_closure3$_closure13$_closure15$_closure16@190bc2b8] on object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.
```

[Add sourcesJar task to custom Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870567/add-sourcesjar-task-to-custom-gradle-plugin/) looks like a similar problem but it is a different error and their solution doesn't work anyway.

The relevant parts of my build.gradle are:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
            artifact testJar {
                classifier "tests"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.url'
            credentials {
                username "$username"
                password "$password"
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task testJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    classifier = 'tests'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out: https://docs.gradle.org/5.5.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:deferred_configuration says that a `publishing` block was executed after the rest of the project in Gradle 4, but not in Gradle 5.

So, changing

```
artifact sourcesJar {
   classifier "sources"
}
artifact testJar {
   classifier "tests"
}
```

to

```
afterEvaluate {
    artifact sourcesJar {
        classifier "sources"
    }
    artifact testJar {
        classifier "tests"
    }
}
```

got me a little further. With that change I then got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'common'.
> Cannot create a Publication named 'sourcesJar' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Publication to create. Known subtypes are: MavenPublication
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cannot-create-a-publication-named-x/3726 and [Gradle: Using 'maven-publish' plugin in custom standalone plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748458/gradle-using-maven-publish-plugin-in-custom-standalone-plugin) seem to suggest that a prefix of project. should fix it.

So changing it to:

```
afterEvaluate {
    artifact project.sourcesJar {
        classifier "sources"
    }
    artifact project.testJar {
        classifier "tests"
    }
}
```

seems to work, though I'm a little iffy on the project. prefix.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to add the following that Gradle was aware about the artifacts:

```
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

Then I was able to use it this way:

```
publishing.publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
    }
}
```

Javadoc as well as Sources were published. There seems to be no need to add the `afterEvaluate` block.

Answer (score -2):

In this block:

```
artifact sourcesJar {
   classifier "sources"
}
artifact testJar {
   classifier "tests"
}
```

remove the closures...just make it look like this:

```
artifact sourcesJar
artifact testJar
```

Comment: I get a slightly different error message now: Could not get unknown property 'sourcesJar' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.